# Want to Show images on blade template that stored in array formet in Database on Laravel 8

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Please need help. I stored images as an array in the database. So how I decode the array images on the blade view template. My controller is like that

```
public function store(Request $req){
    $req->validate([
      'name' => 'required',
      'imageFile' => 'required',
      'imageFile.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,csv,txt,pdf|max:2048'
    ]);

    if($req->hasfile('imageFile')) {
        foreach($req->file('imageFile') as $file)
        {
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $name);  
            $imgData[] = $name;  
        }

        $fileModal = new Image();
        $fileModal->name = $req->input('name');
        $fileModal->image_path = json_encode($imgData);
        
       
        $fileModal->save();

       return back()->with('success', 'Images has successfully uploaded!');
    }
  }
```

and the image Model is like that...

```
 class Image extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'image_path'
    ];
 
}
```

I already successfully stored the data that images data as an array in the database.
[image]

But when I use this code it shows the array data, not images.

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset("uploads/".$photo->image_path) }}" alt="{{ $photo->name }}" style="width:150px; height:auto;">
```

After that, I will place another code :

```
@foreach ($photos as $photo)
      @php $filenames = json_decode($photo->image_path); @endphp
                
      @foreach ($filenames as $singlefilename)    
           <img src="{{ url('uploads/' . $singlefilename) }}" width="100px"/>
      @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

but at that time it shows all images that contained the folder but I need just that rows array images according to id. Please I need help. Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

You have bound multiple img paths with a single name, there is no key to pinpoint a single img path. It's like there is a group of people without identity, how can you find the one you want?

Comment: opps it's my mistake but the image path are now edited. but how i retrieve the images array to string ?

Comment: Aren't they are string when retrieved from the array, the json_decoded array.